# Interpreting Coefficients of a Linear Model

Tags: r, model, mean, lm

I'm having difficulty in interpreting the results of a linear model. I have two categorical: States (AK, IL, MO, KS) and Roads (Con, Cem, Mud) and one continuous predictor variable (Days). My response variable is also continuous (index). I'm using a AIC framework for model selection. The model (best) with lowest AIC is as follows:

```
model<-lm(index ~ State + Roads*Days, data=myDat)

coef(model)

 >(Intercept)                 StateIL 
 1.376299e+00               -6.745194e-03 
 StateMO                     StateKS 
-6.767209e-02                8.852979e-03
 RoadCem                     RoadMud
-3.633496e-01                7.555775e-01
 Days                        RoadCem:Days
-5.365565e-06               -9.961142e-05
 RoadMud:Days 
 8.822059e-05
```

I am wanting to extract the predicted mean for each of the above with respect to intercept which is the predicted mean for StateAK RoadCon at Day 0.

Comment: For categorical variables, the coefficient represents the estimate when that categorical variable takes value 1 (exists). Also, the first value is used as baseline. So, your intercept incorporates StateAK, RoadCon and Day 0 already.

Answer (score 1):

Coefficients  `RoadCem` and `RoadMud` will differ from `RoadCon` at Day==0 by -3.633496e-01 and 7.555775e-01 respectively. The `Days` coefficient, -5.365565e-06,  is the amount by which `index` will decrease for `RoadCon` cases on each succeeding day. Then the `RoadCem:Days` coefficient,   -9.961142e-05, is the amount of decrease from that value with each successive day, while `RoadMud:Days` coefficient, 8.822059e-05, is the amount of increase from the baseline of (1.376299e+00 + 7.555775e-01) on each succeeding day for that type of Road. These three lines will be shifted up or down for the other States by the amount of their respective coefficients.

In R you could construct a set of values that would cover the range of possibilities with `expand.grid` and give this to the `newdata` argument of `predict.lm`. You would be able to plot the lines with `matplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm trying to get the predicted mean for each state, for each Road and for each interaction term between Road and Days from the above model. I want to build a plot of predicted mean for each category using plotrix in R with confidence intervals.

Comment: There is no "predicted mean" for an interaction term. This seems obviously the case for models with interactions involving continuous variables, but I would argue that it also applies to interactions that only involve discrete ('factor') variables. The only way to talk about predictions from such models is to construct scenarios of specific values to be compared against each other. This is so because the existence of interactions means that more than one term will be contributing to a prediction. (And I already laid out a plan for building a dataset needed to make an informative plot.)